# Numpy Loading a File Showing All Zeros

Tags: python, numpy

I downloaded a npy file from Google, which is 96 MB. I am trying to load the file but I get all ZEROS as shown in the output below:

Using Python 3.6

```
>>> import numpy as np 
>>> a = np.load("full_numpy_bitmap_cat.npy", allow_pickle=True) 
>>> a = np.load("full_numpy_bitmap_cat.npy", allow_pickle=True, fix_imports=True) 
>>> a
array([[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       ...,
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8)
>>>
```

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: You look like a pretty experienced coder, so don’t take this as offensive: What actions have you taken to verify the data? Do you know what should look like? If so, can you share a sample if it? Maybe try a[a<>0] and see if any of the data is not zero?

Comment: Actually I don't know what the data will look like. I got the data from https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser/quickdraw_dataset/full/numpy_bitmap

Comment: Try printing `a.max()` and `a.mean()` It might be an image with a black border, i.e. zeroes. Get `a.shape` too.

Comment: Try `from PIL import Image` then `Image.fromarray(a).show()`

Comment: @MarkSetchell There is no module called PIL??

Comment: The module is called `pillow`, so you would need `pip install pillow` if you want to install it.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I edited the original question to show what I see. It should be hundreds of clipart images but that is what I see.

Comment: I cannot access the data in your link (it is behind Terms and Conditions I don't choose to sign up to) or I would help more.

Answer (score 0):

That's not because you see zeros when printing that everything is zeros. I downloaded the file, I have not only zeros.

```
import numpy as npy
image = npy.load("full_numpy_bitmap_cat.npy")
print(" number of non-zeros", len(npy.nonzero(image)[0]) )
```